# Webview unusable after draw method called

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to extract webview screenshot (even if there is a scroll) and to save it.
My problem is after `webview.draw()` method called, webview is now an image an is unusable as a webview.
If there a way to prevent that behavior ?

Important : I can't just reload webview because user enters fields.

Here's my code :

```
protected void onClicked() {
    mWebView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    mWebView.layout(0, 0, mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            mWebView.getMeasuredHeight());

    mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.buildDrawingCache();

    generateWebViewCapture();
}

/**
 * Create capture of all webview.
 */
@Background
void generateWebViewCapture() {

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            mWebView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = bm.getHeight();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
    mWebView.draw(canvas);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            mWebView.invalidate();
        }
    });

    try {
        String path = getReportPath();
        File file = new File(path, "/report-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
        OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

To fix the problem, remove that line :

```
mWebView.layout(0, 0, mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(),
        mWebView.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Comment: try webview.invalidate()

Comment: Try use setDrawingCacheEnabled() to get screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it's what i'm doing, have a look to my code

Comment: You enabled it and you should disable it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)` after you get the `bitmap`!

```
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // remove mWebView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm= mWebView.getDrawingCache();

 //remove   generateWebViewCapture();
   try {
    String path = getReportPath();
    File file = new File(path, "/report-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

This code is worked on my mobile:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testm);
        final WebView mWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.csdn.net/");
        findViewById(R.id.iv_0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                // remove mWebView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm= mWebView.getDrawingCache();

                //remove   generateWebViewCapture();
                try {
                    String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
                    File file = new File(path, "/report-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
                    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: No it still do not works. I've edited the code adding setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) after draw method call

Comment: Did you get some error?Try add  it after generateWebViewCapture().

Comment: What's the real problem?

Comment: I haven't noticed it .

Answer (score 0):

It does not work on Android R.

```
WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()
```

Add ScrollView, It works.

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```